# Where can I get the repositories for old Ubuntu versions?

Tags: ubuntu

Where can I get the old repositories for Ubuntu versions? In my case, it's 9.04 Jaunty?

I found all the official repositories and their mirrors have been removed. I am wondering where I can get the repository list for this version?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Your system is End-of-Life (EOL), therefore not officially supported. Unless you have a good reason for sticking with 9.04, **upgrade to a newer version**. Go to the next [long-term supported release](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) for Ubuntu, which will continue to receive updates.

To access old Ubuntu repositories, take a look at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/.

There is also an [official Ubuntu documentation for EOL upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades)

They say you should be able to access your packages by putting the following into `/etc/apt/sources.list`. **Important:** Change `CODENAME` to your distribution's code name, e.g. `jaunty`.

```
## EOL upgrade sources.list
# Required
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ CODENAME main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ CODENAME-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ CODENAME-security main restricted universe multiverse

# Optional
#deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ CODENAME-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Just run `apt-get update` and you can use them.

Comment: The link to thinkbeforetype.com is dead as of October 2014.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Legacy projects with very old software version dependencies are difficult to upgrade (plus no one wants to take responsibility of any bugs of doing that) Sometimes we need to stay old.

Comment: Recovering some old videos from a camera that won't work with the new firewire stack thanks to this answer and ubuntu lucid 10.04.

Comment: The above works for architectures `i386`, `amd64`, but what about, e.g., `arm64` (for which you originally would pull from `ports.ubuntu.com`)?

Comment: @MarkusUeberall I don't know. I think Ubuntu has only had builds for arm64 from 16.04 onwards … ?

Comment: It's a developer's slip of the tongue, but @slhck meant to say 'End-Of-Life' instead.

Comment: @onirix Duh, fixed, 12 years later!

Answer (score 0):

You may try the ustc mirror ...

http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu-old-releases/ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks for contributing itfanr. In order for your contribution to be more helpful to other users, please take a moment to read some guidelines of good answers, especially the section "Provide context for links" here: https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer Cheers!

Comment: This link worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you actually need, replace the entries in /etc/apt/sources.list

Example: In my case, I need ports for arm (32), for 'precise'.
In this file, the original sources were `//ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/`.
All occurrences needed to be replaced by `//old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`.
It wasn't anything but obvious, that the name of the sub-dir also had to be changed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).