# How to install top & htop on Ubuntu 8.04.2 LTS (hardy)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get, top

### Env.

- Rackspace
- Ubuntu 8.04.2 LTS (hardy)

I am in a corner situation where I need to maintain carefully a legacy server before I can plant for an upgrade.

Actually an upgrade is not an option, I need to rebuild that server from scratch.

In the meantime, I am trying to get a minimum of tools installed to monitor the server but I haven't been able to install any package.

```
root@beard:~# sudo apt-get install htop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  htop
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 115 not upgraded.
Need to get 52.5kB of archives.
After this operation, 197kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  htop
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/universe htop 0.6.6+svn20070915-1ubuntu0.2
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/universe htop 0.6.6+svn20070915-1ubuntu0.2
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/h/htop/htop_0.6.6+svn20070915-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

and

```
root@beard:~# apt-get update --fix-missing
Err http://packages.cloudkick.com hardy Release.gpg
  Could not resolve 'packages.cloudkick.com'
Hit http://apt.newrelic.com newrelic Release.gpg                                                                                                         
Hit http://apt.newrelic.com newrelic Release                                                                                                             
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security Release.gpg                   
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security Release                       
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates Release.gpg            
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/main Packages        
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/restricted Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/universe Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/main Sources         
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/restricted Sources   
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/universe Sources     
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy Release                        
Err http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/main Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/restricted Packages  
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/universe Packages    
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/main Sources         
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/restricted Sources   
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com hardy-security/universe Sources     
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
Hit http://apt.newrelic.com newrelic/non-free Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates Release
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/main Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/restricted Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/universe Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/main Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/restricted Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/universe Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/main Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/restricted Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/universe Packages
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/main Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/restricted Sources
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/universe Sources
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/main Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/restricted Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/universe Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/main Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/restricted Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy/universe Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/main Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/restricted Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/universe Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/main Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/restricted Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com hardy-updates/universe Sources
  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.cloudkick.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'packages.cloudkick.com'

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-security/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-security/main/source/Sources.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-security/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-security/universe/source/Sources.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy/main/source/Sources.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy/universe/source/Sources.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-updates/restricted/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-updates/main/source/Sources.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-updates/restricted/source/Sources.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/hardy-updates/universe/source/Sources.gz  404 Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.153 80]

W: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

#### ping

```
root@beard:~# ping 91.189.88.153
PING 91.189.88.153 (91.189.88.153) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 91.189.88.153: icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=108 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.88.153: icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=108 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.88.153: icmp_seq=3 ttl=47 time=108 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.88.153: icmp_seq=4 ttl=47 time=108 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.88.153: icmp_seq=5 ttl=47 time=108 ms
```

Comment: Are you able to ping the ip address in question?

Comment: Yes I do. I will update the question with the ping response

Comment: You're using a deprecated version of Ubuntu which isn't available anymore on official mirror. I would recommend you to migrate to a newer release. If you really can't, you can use this archive mirror: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/

Comment: I can't for now. This would be a major task that need more preparation. See you can't just upgrade an old ubuntu hardy instance, it's on a different Rackspace hardware, you need to create a new server and install everything from scratch. Thanks for the link BTW, that's a start.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to open repository configuration file and change the repo location as originally suggested by piernov in a comment or in this [answer.](https://superuser.com/a/339572/391035) The file you need to edit is `/etc/apt/sources.list` and you need to replace all instances of `archive.ubuntu.com` and `security.ubuntu.com` with `old-releases.ubuntu.com`.
After that, run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This should get you back on the horse while you are still working on setting up a new server.